# Multiprocessing not using whole CPU

Tags: python, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, montecarlo

I'm testing python's module "multiprocessing". I'm trying to compute pi using a montecarlo technique using my 12 threads ryzen 5 5600.

The problem is that my cpu is not fully used, instead only 47% is used. I leave you my code below, changing the value of n_cpu leads to not so different core usage, instead increasing N by 1 order of magnitude can increase the load up to 77%... but i believed that N shouldn't affect the number of processes...
Please help me understand how to correctly parallelize my code, thanks.

```
import random
import math
import numpy as np
import multiprocessing
from multiprocessing import Pool

def sample(n):
    n_inside_circle = 0
    for i in range(n):
        x = random.random()
        y = random.random()
        if x**2 + y**2 < 1.0:
            n_inside_circle += 1
    return n_inside_circle

N_test=1000
N=12*10**4
n_cpu = 12
pi=0

for j in range(N_test):
    part_count=[int(N/n_cpu)] * n_cpu
    pool = Pool(processes=n_cpu)
    results = pool.map(sample, part_count)
    pool.close()
    pi += sum(results)/(N*1.0)*4

print(pi/N_test)
```

Comment: Because the CPU is not the bottleneck in an algorithm which does not do a lot of calculation?

Comment: @zvone I'm trying to learn how to parallelize task, this is an example, in principle I expect the program to run simultaneously 12 processes, using all threads of my cpu, unfortunately this does not happens, in fact the cpu usage is way below 100%

Comment: You have to consider the overhead(s) involved in sub-process management including, but not limited to, the serialisation of data being passed between the main program and the sub-processes. On my machine, the *sample()* function runs in ~0.002s for n=12_000. Thus it is clear that the time spent performing the calculations is almost insignificant when compared to the aforementioned overheads

Comment: @Pingu thanks for your explanation, now I'm starting to understand, given the fact that the time spent inside the function sample() is too small compared to the overhead, it is unlikely to see my threads working altogether simultaneously, if I increase N the time spent inside sample will dominate and this is why I observe the increasing in cpu usage. I set N to 10**6 and in fact I reach nearly 100% cpu utilization with n_cpu=12, I kept this value of N and I tried to reduce the value of n_cpu: I observed the correct cpu usage scaling, therefore I think to have solved my problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lack of cpu use is because you are sending chunks of data to multiple new process pools instead of all at once to a single process pool.

simply using

```
pool = Pool(processes=n_cpu)
for j in range(N_test):
    part_count=[int(N/n_cpu)] * n_cpu
    results = pool.map(sample, part_count)
    pi += sum(results)/(N*1.0)*4
pool.close()
```

should have some speed up

To optimize this further

We can change the way the jobs are split up to have more samples for a single process.

We can use Numpy's vectorized random functions that will run faster than random.random().

Finally for the last bit of speed, we can use numba with a threadpool to reduce overhead even more.

```
import time
import numpy as np
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool
from numba import jit

@jit(nogil=True, parallel=True, fastmath=True)
def sample(n):
    x = np.random.random(n)
    y = np.random.random(n)
    inside_circle = np.square(x) + np.square(y) < 1.0
    return int(np.sum(inside_circle))

total_samples = int(3e9)
function_limit = int(1e7)
n_cpu = 12
pi=0

assert total_samples%function_limit == 0

start = time.perf_counter()
with ThreadPool(n_cpu) as pool:
    part_count=[function_limit] * (total_samples//function_limit)
    results = pool.map(sample, part_count)
    pi = 4*sum(results)/(total_samples)
end = time.perf_counter()
print(pi)
print(round(end-start,3), "seconds taken")
```

resulting in

```
3.141589756
6.982 seconds taken
```

Comment: Note that Numba is not so useful in this example, especially due to the lazy compilation. It is better to use a loop so to avoid the computation to be memory bound and take a lot of memory. This loop can then run in parallel with `prange`. The function can be eagerly compiled once the signature is provided. Using `prange` is better than multiprocessing because `prange` use multi-threading with a lower overhead and simpler thanks to shared memory (and no GIL/pickling). Multiprocessing also force the function to be recompiled in each process (slow). One fixed, it should be much faster.

Comment: @JérômeRichard hi, updated the parralel and fastmath flags to speed up the code. I'm not sure how prange could be used here - could you help me out with it? Also this code is already using a ThreadPool and the compilation is only done once.

Comment: Thank you very much for your practical advice to speed up the code using numpy and threadpool!

Comment: @arrmansa The function `sample` in the OP code is a good start for Numba: one just need to add the `@jit` with `parallel=True, fastmath=True` (possibly the signature too) and use `prange` instead of `range` in the code and that's all. AFAIK, `parallel=True` is useless without `prange` here.

Comment: @JérômeRichard Just tried out OP's code with prange and jit. It is faster than my initial code which is really cool.  I then tried using np.sum instead of np.count_nonzero and it became faster than the python version. Also my code without parallel=True takes 28 s instead of 8s so it definitely is doing something, I think numba does some parallel optimizations automatically.

Comment: @arrmansa Ha, you are right! I updated Numba to the last version on my Windows machine and it looks like they run some operation in parallel new. My bad. The loop based approach is still faster because it is less memory bound but this is good to know. Thank you for the information.